# android, how do i put/load images from cache memory?

Tags: android, memory-management, gridview

I my project I have an activity which has a grid view. This grid view will show images which are loaded from the Internet. Everything is fine and I can see my images in activity. However, because I'm using a grid adapter, scrolling of the screen is not smooth and it lags.

What is the best practice in terms of smooth scrolling and memory management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try Lazy Loading in GridView. check below link.

http://blog.jamesbaca.net/?p=67

OR

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList